# cmd скрипт для добавления треков в плейлист

Tags: cmd, m3u

Вот пытался сделать скрипт но не знаю как сделать чтобы после трека New_Audio03 добавлялась песня New_Audio01 и так по кругу до конца плейлиста.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "playlist=playlist.m3u"
set "new_song1=New_Audio01.mp.mp3"
set "new_song2=New_Audio02.mp.mp3"
set "new_song3=New_Audio03.mp.mp3"
set "new_playlist=new_playlist.m3u"

(for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /n "^" "%playlist%"') do (
  set "line=%%b"
  if %%a equ 16 (
    echo.
    echo.#EXTINF:0,!new_song1!
    echo.!new_song1!
    echo.
  ) else if %%a equ 31 (
    echo.
    echo.#EXTINF:0,!new_song2!
    echo.!new_song2!
    echo.
  ) else if %%a equ 46 (
    echo.
    echo.#EXTINF:0,!new_song3!
    echo.!new_song3!
    echo.
  ) else (
    echo(!line!
  )
)) > "%new_playlist%"
```

Добрый день помогите со скриптом cmd.
у меня есть готовый аудио плейлист и мне нужно добавить в него несколько треков.
Грубо говоря у меня есть 3 трека которые нужно по очереди вставить через каждых 5 текущих треков до конца моего плейлиста вот пример который мне нужно получить.
это треки которые мне нужно добавить в плейлист New_Audio01.mp3, New_Audio02.mp3, New_Audio03.mp3
желательно в переменной добавлять новые треки которые нужно вставить в плейлист

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:0,Track1.mp3
Track1.mp3

#EXTINF:0,Track2.mp3
Track2.mp3

#EXTINF:0,Track3.mp3
Track3.mp3

#EXTINF:0,Track4.mp3
Track4.mp3

#EXTINF:0,Track5.mp3
Track5.mp3

#EXTINF:0,New_Audio01.mp3
New_Audio01.mp3

#EXTINF:0,Track6.mp3
Track6.mp3

#EXTINF:0,Track7.mp3
Track7.mp3

#EXTINF:0,Track8.mp3
Track8.mp3

#EXTINF:0,Track9.mp3
Track9.mp3

#EXTINF:0,Track10.mp3
Track10.mp3

#EXTINF:0,New_Audio02.mp3
New_Audio02.mp3

#EXTINF:0,Track11.mp3
Track11.mp3

#EXTINF:0,Track12.mp3
Track12.mp3

#EXTINF:0,Track13.mp3
Track13.mp3

#EXTINF:0,Track14.mp3
Track14.mp3

#EXTINF:0,Track15.mp3
Track15.mp3

#EXTINF:0,New_Audio03.mp3
New_Audio03.mp3

#EXTINF:0,Track16.mp3
Track16.mp3

#EXTINF:0,Track17.mp3
Track17.mp3

#EXTINF:0,Track18.mp3
Track18.mp3

#EXTINF:0,Track19.mp3
Track9.mp3

#EXTINF:0,Track20.mp3
Track20.mp3

#EXTINF:0,New_Audio01.mp3
New_Audio01.mp3

#EXTINF:0,Track21.mp3
Track21.mp3

#EXTINF:0,Track22.mp3
Track22mp3

#EXTINF:0,Track23.mp3
Track23.mp3

#EXTINF:0,Track24.mp3
Track24.mp3

#EXTINF:0,Track25.mp3
Track25.mp3

#EXTINF:0,New_Audio02.mp3
New_Audio02.mp3

#EXTINF:0,Track26.mp3
Track26.mp3

#EXTINF:0,Track27.mp3
Track27mp3

#EXTINF:0,Track28.mp3
Track28.mp3

#EXTINF:0,Track29.mp3
Track29.mp3
```

Comment: Добрый день, на этом сайте принято помогать с задачами, а не решать за кого-то либо. Поэтому, пожалуйста, добавьте вашу попытку решить задачу (в виде кода в вопросе), иначе вопрос может быть закрыт. Ознакомьтесь с https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

Получилось

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "playlist=playlist.m3u"
set "new_song1=song1.mp3"
set "new_song2=song2.mp3"
set "new_song3=song3.mp3"
set "new_playlist=new_playlist.m3u"

set /a count=1
set "new_song=!new_song1!"
(for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /n "^" "%playlist%"') do (
  set "line=%%b"
  echo(!line!
  if !count! equ 15 (
    echo.
    echo.#EXTINF:0,!new_song!
    echo.!new_song!
    set /a count=0
    if "!new_song!"=="!new_song1!" (
      set "new_song=!new_song2!"
    ) else if "!new_song!"=="!new_song2!" (
      set "new_song=!new_song3!"
    ) else (
      set "new_song=!new_song1!"
    )
  )
  set /a count+=1
)) > "%new_playlist%"
```

помогите с переменной, чтобы изменить только одну строку (пример `set "list_song=song1.mp3*song2.mp3*song3.mp3*song4.mp3*song5.mp3"`)
при добавлении или удаления трека

к примеру если я захочу добавить song4.mp3

то нужно еще добавить и это

```
set "new_song=!new_song4!"
```

set "new_song3=song4.mp3"
) else if "!new_song!"=="!new_song4!" (